# javascript replace content in div

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I have an ajax script working that fills a div on a page with search results returned from the server.  Each search result has a hyper link with second javascript function that sets hidden input value on the page for posting back to the server, depending on which result is clicked on by user.  All of that is working fine.

However, in the second javascript function I also want to set the contents of the original div to the selected value and I cannot get this to work.

html on starting page

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="getResults(this.value)"><div id="results"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<div id='chosenresult'></div>">
```

markup returned by ajax:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick ="setResult(1)">Result1</a><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick ="setResult(2)">Result2</a><br>
```

Javascript for setResult

```
function setResult(varname) {
document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = varname; //WORKS FINE
document.getElementById('results').value = varname; //DOES NOT WORK
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = varname; //ALTERNATIVE ALSO DOES NOT WORK
return false;
}
```

In other words, I can set the value in the hidden input field, but cannot replace the contents of the "results" div.

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT:

I FOUND THE MISTAKE.  Putting a div in the value for the hidden input tab worked as a hack to set the value but was unecessary and seems to have broken the code so the results div was not set.  In lieu of a div, simply giving an id to the hidden input tab and setting its value in javascript works as follows:

html

```
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="hidden" name = "result" id="chosenresult">
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = varname; //WORKS FINE
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = varname; //NOW WORKS
```

Comment: EDIT: heh, sorry about that. Perhaps you need to escape the html that is going into the second input's value?

Comment: dont't use `var` as variable/argument name.

Comment: `document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = var; //WORKS FINE` — It shouldn't do. You don't have a div with that ID in the code.

Comment: @Quentin probably the browser reads `value="<div id='chosenresult'></div>">` and tries to fix it closing the input tag.

Comment: Also, `document.getElementById('results').value = var` assigns to a newly made value property on the results div, which is useless. Perhaps you mean `document.getElementById('result').value = var`

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada — No, the attribute value is quoted, that won't happen.

Comment: When creating your reduced test case, you have introduced a bunch of errors. The behaviour of [your code](http://jsfiddle.net/zuxW4/) does not match your description of the problems. Please create a reduced test case that accurately reflects the problems you are having.

Comment: Re edit: You've now edited three of your four cases of using `var` instead of `varname` but it still doesn't work. Please *test* the code you are writing to see if it behaves as you expect (note any errors reported in the browser's error console).

Comment: What are you reading?  I do have a div named "results" and also one name "chosenrsult".  I have not made errors.  You are reading incorrectly.

Comment: @user1260310 — You do not have a div with the id `chosenrsult`. You do have `value="<div id='chosenresult'></div>"`, but that is a value attribute containing a string of text and is not treated as an element.

Comment: That part of the code and that div is working fine...reread question.  The issue is the other div, results. If you don't have anything constructive to add to discussion, please refrain from commenting

Comment: Quentin, your fiddle has the links pre created. Perhaps something more like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YBAU2/2/) is what he intends? Also, what is going wrong is that the code breaks at chosenresult and does not get to the results div. Quentin is actually correct, and more importantly, is giving you his time. No need to be testy. :)

Comment: @Asad — There was enough wrong with the code that I didn't try to complicate it by guessing how the links were being dynamically added :)

Comment: @user1260310 — It *isn't* working fine, hence my comment about your description of the problem not matching the results of running the code you provided.

Comment: As far as can it be understood within your question `document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = varname` is not working with your html. If it is prove it with http://jsfiddle.net or something like that. P.S. http://jsfiddle.net/AVNws/2/

Answer (score 4):

First - As @Muthu Kumaran told you, please don't use "var" as a identifier.

Second - Why do you have a div inside the input value?

```
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<div id='chosenresult'></div>"
```

If you have this markup:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="getResults(this.value)">
<div id="results"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="result" value="<div id='chosenresult'></div>">
```

You are creating one input without id. Then you create **at the same level** a div called "results" and then you create another unnamed input than has a value than looks like HTML markup.

So when you do

```
document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = var;
```

You are there is no element with id "chosenresult" it must crash so no other line on this function will be executed. Anyway lets read them:

```
document.getElementById('results').value = var;
```

Divs have no property callled "value", use innerHTML instead

```
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = var;
```

This must work, but it will modify the innerHTML of a div between both inputs, no the input's values

So if you are trying to modify the input value you must name the input itself:

```
<input id="results" type="text" onkeyup="getResults(this.value)">
<input id="chosenresult" type="hidden" name="result" value="">
```

And then modify it's "value" property:

```
document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = var;
document.getElementById('results').value = var;
```

Comment: Putting the div chosenresult inside the value property actually works fine.  It correctly sets the value inside the tag.  However, I will try moving the entire hiddent tag to the javascript to see if this helps.

Comment: But there is no div "chosenresult" then, when you try to access `document.getElementById('chosenresult').value = varname;` it will crash.